# JQuery Serialization Truncates Trailing Whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, thymeleaf

I have a form similar to the following:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input th:field="*{name}"/>
  <input th:field="*{id}"/>
  <button type="button" id="cancelButton" onclick="processCancel()">Cancel</button>
 </form>
```

a JS method that passes the serialized  form off to the web layer to be compared to the current data base record

```
function processCancel() {
   let data = $('#myForm').serialize();

   $.ajax({
       url: "compare",
       data: data,
       success: function (change) {
           if (!change) {
               $('#reload').click();
           }},
       async:false
   });
}
```

and a web controller that compares the objects

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/compare", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody boolean compare(@ModelAttribute(name = "form") SomeObject form) {
        SomeObject dbRecord = //get the record from the db

        return !dbRecord.equals(form);
    }
```

Some of the database records have trailing white space; for example: `name="someName  "`.  The problem is `serialize()` seems to truncate trailing white spaces so when the `name` field makes it back to the web layer it is `name="someName"` instead of `name="someName   "` which causes any comparison between the object from the form and the database record to fail.

Is there any way to prevent the serialization from truncating the trailing white space?

Comment: why would you ever use trailing whitespace in a database? The data would be really difficult to manage.

Comment: @zfrisch I agree, but it is existing data that can not change so unfortunately I have to work with it

Comment: If that is the case, you will need to not use serialization and just capture the data manually.

Comment: Or add a trim() to the data received from the DB so comparison can be correct.

Comment: If space doesn't matter here, I agree with @Twisty suggestion ! You just trim() what's coming from the DB.